# Error running Grails 3 application on CMD

Tags: grails, cmd

I am new to Grails and never made any project on it. I followed some tutorials and downloaded both Grails and JDK and set my environment variables exactly as specified, but when I tried to run the application, I got this error and my application is not running:

> Error initializing classpath: could not determine java version from '10.0.2'

[image: Picture link that shows the complete process i followed.]

I just used CMD and none of the IDE is used, please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Looks like you are using Java 10 better use Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check classpath of both for Java & Grails by running these command `java -version` & `grails -version`

[image]

If you found problem in classpath then solve by this way http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners-setup-your-windows-development-environment/

Although its better to use Java 8, not Java 10

Comment: Thanks alot, the previous problem has been solved by using Java 8 instead of Java 10. But now there is this new problem. I'll ask about it in community

Comment: Ok you are welcome to ask again. If you like my answer please tick as correct.